# Proving Power Set of $\mathbb N$ is Uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I'm getting hung up on a proof that I remember being fairly easy... Showing that the power set of $\mathbb N$ is uncountable. Supposing it's countable, say $A=\{A_1,...\}$, we choose a set $B$ composed of elements $b_i$, where $b_i\notin  A$. How to we guarantee that $B$ isn't the naturals itself, an element of its own power set? Thanks!

Comment: The usual proof is different, let $f\colon \mathbb{N}\to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ be any map. Let $A = \{ n \in \mathbb{N} : n \notin f(n)\}$. Then $A$ is not in the image of $f$, so $f$ is not surjective.

Comment: You'll always get an element of the power set of $\mathbb N$, and you could get $\mathbb N$ itself.  The point is that the element you get will not be in the sequence. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @DanielFischer : When you say the usual proof is different, is the difference you have in mind only that it doesn't start with the assumption that it's surjective? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy No, I mean I'm too sleepy to see that it's in fact the same.

Comment: @DanielFischer : In some contexts it's important to distinguish between the version that is by contradiction and the one that's not done that way.  But in such cases, I'd be explicit about that being the difference. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3):

It does not matter if $B$ is empty, $\Bbb N$, or anything. The point is that $B$ is *not* one of the $A_i$'s.

Just to clarify, $B$ should be defined as $\{i\in\Bbb N\mid i\notin A_i\}$, rather than involving $b_i$'s.

Answer (score 1):

It is better proved in this way.

Enumerate all natural number as $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n\cdots$. Suppose $A=\{a_{n_i}|\:i\in\Bbb{N}\}$ be a subset of $a_n$.

Now let
$$
r=c_1c_2\cdots c_n\cdots\quad\text{where }c_n=\begin{cases}1, \quad\text{if }a_n\in A\\0,\quad\text{if }a_n\notin A\end{cases}
$$
Then it is clear that each $A$ corresponds to a $r$. We prove that $r$ can not be enumerated.

If not, let $r_k=c_{1k}c_{2k}\cdots c_{nk}\cdots$ be an enumeration, where $k\in\Bbb{N},\:c_{nk}\in\{0,1\}$. Let $r'=d_{1}\cdots d_{n}\cdots, \:d_{n}\ne c_{nn}$. Then $\forall k\:r'\ne r_k\:$ for $d_k\ne r_{kk}$, which means $r'$ is not in the enumeration.

The contradiction means $r$ can not be enumerated and must be uncountable, and so is all the number of $A$, or power set of $\Bbb{N}$.

Comment: This seems to really obfuscate the heart of the proof; it takes us from $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ to $\mathbb R$ and back for no particular reason (which is actually problematic when we note that binary representations aren't unique and which doesn't really accomplish anything).